# prevent entering characters more than given number of times in a column range-excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

here is my excel sheet example:

[image]

```
Private Sub test2()

Dim count As Long
Dim a As String
Dim Act As Integer

Worksheets("test").Activate
a = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
' "count" counts the occorance of "b"
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A16"), a)
Act = ActiveCell
If count > Act Then
MsgBox "exceeded"
Else
 MsgBox count
End If

End Sub
`
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @JohnColeman I think the title itself is the question, hehe

Comment: @Sgdva Doubtless that is related to it, but what is the issue with the code? I have no motivation to run it and *guess* what the issue is.

Comment: @JohnColeman Agreed, kind of messed up the question but, I think precisely is the scope which is wrong -on the asker side-

Answer (score 0):

***Steps Required***

1. You need the [Worksheet_Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

2. Once you have understood that you need to do something like the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ItemMultipleData As Range
For Each ItemMultipleData In Target 'handles multiple cells, paste, del, etc
If Not Intersect(ItemMultipleData, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), ItemMultipleData.Value) > 3 Then MsgBox ("Not allowed"): ItemMultipleData.Value = ""
End If
Next ItemMultipleData
End sub
```